# NodeJS Express allow handeful requests to skip authentication check

Tags: node.js, regex, express

Is there a request path regex matcher in NodeJS , basically I would like to build a capability to allow certain paths to skip token validation.
How to do it in Express.

```
function verifyToken(req, res, next) {
  // Get auth header value
  const whitelistPaths = ["/ping","**/swagger-ui.html/**","/health/*"];
  if(req.path matches any of values in whitelist array) , call next()
  const bearerHeader = req.headers["Authorization"];
  Authentication check
```

```
router.get("*", verifyToken, apiProxy);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just use a regex as the path :

`router.get((\/ping)|(.*\/swagger-ui\.html)|(\/health\/.*), verifyToken, apiProxy);`

this will catch /ping or /swagger-ui.html or /health

here is the docs: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Comment: I dont want it at that place , I need it inside verifyToken middleware function. How do I do it there .

Comment: why ? those paths should enter `verifyToken` middleware , other paths - should not.

Comment: I want all paths to enter verifyToken middleware .

Comment: this is not what you wrote in your question, so please next time be more specific: `
Is there a request path regex matcher` - this is exactly what i answered.

Comment: If I go with your approach, how do I match all other paths. Meaning for three paths, i wouldn't like verifyToken middleware to be called , for anything else , verifyToken middleware should be called.

Comment: after this regex route just add route for all other routes ... and don't put `verifyToken` on them .

Comment: router.get("*",  apiProxy); If I put this , then all requests hit this instead of above route

Comment: after the route in the answer ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242002/discussion-between-ladu-anand-and-ddor254).